# error - Spray-http: not found: type HttpBody

Tags: scala, akka, spray, spray-json

I am using till now spray - 1.1-M7 but now I changed to 1.3.3. There is HttpBody in 1.1-M7 but that was not exist in 1.3.3 version. So what is the alternative I have to do in my code.

My code looks like this: What do I have to do to get:

```
implicit def json4sUnmarshaller[T: Manifest] = {
    Unmarshaller[T](`application/json`) {
      case x: HttpBody ⇒
        read[T](cleanupString(x.asString))
    }
  }
```

Comment: I didn't write my unmarshallers this way so I'm not sure it that'll work, but the type you are looking for is `HttpEntity`

Comment: I'd recommend switching to akka-http on the long term.

Comment: Thanks @FredericA. It looks working.

Comment: @Sun you are most welcome, I've added it as proposed answer for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you are looking for is `HttpEntity`